# Uib datepicker ng-change not firing on date selection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to trigger a call to a function on change of the date in the uib datepicker however the ng-change attribute doesn't seem to be getting applied. I've tried using a watcher but since we're not using $scope in our controller I haven't been able to find a solution that works with that method. See code below:

```
<span class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-default"
                      data-test="start-date-button"
                      ng-click="startDateIsOpen = !startDateIsOpen"
                      type="button">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                <span class="sr-only" translate>{{::'datePicker.openDatePicker'}}</span>
              </button>
            </span>
            <input class="form-control"
                   is-open="startDateIsOpen"
                   name="startDate"
                   ng-attr-aria-describedby="{{conditionsController.showError(conditionsController.newConditionAttributes, 'startDate') ?
                       'new-condition-start-date-errors' : undefined}}"
                   ng-change="conditionsController.setMinStartDate(conditionsController.newCondition.editCondition.startDate)"
                   ng-model="conditionsController.newCondition.editCondition.startDate"
                   ng-required="conditionsController.newCondition.editCondition.startTime"
                   popup-placement="top-left"
                   type="text"
                   uib-datepicker-popup="{{dateFormat}}"/>
          </span>
```

Any ideas on why this wouldn't be working?

Comment: can you make a demo using jsfiddle or plunker ?

Comment: One thing of note, if your picker is bound to `conditionsController.newCondition.editCondition.startDate` why do you need to pass it into the `setMinStartDate` function? Can't you just reference it inside the controller?